# Let S be a nonempty set in R which is bounded above and T is the set of all upper bounds for S. Show that sup S = inf T .

Tags: real-analysis

Let S be a nonempty set in R which is bounded above and T is the set of all upper bounds for S , T ={ x is in R : x is an upperbound for S } . Show that sup S = inf T .

Comment: *As I mentioned to you on your last question*, **to get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far**. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself. Also, some would consider your post rude because it is a command ("Show"), not a request for help, so please consider rewriting it.

Answer (score 2):

It is the definition of the dedekind completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ also known as the Dedekind cut. Not that the supremum of a set is the lowest upper bound, and the infimum is the tallest lower bound.